# AngularJS duplicate rows error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

When I want to add the same information it warm me an error of duplicates row.

This problem it comes from $scope.showSal and ng-repeat="rows in showSal".

If I use ng-repeat="rows in showSal track by $index" I can not add duplicate rows and I need it.

How I can make to parse and add duplicates? I tried to make JSON data, but it take error even I use stringify and parse method... maybe I doesn't implemented too well the parsing...

PS: I need to parse an array of objects.

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Research project</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app/research.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nr.</th>
                    <th>An</th>
                    <th>Den</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="rows in showSal">
                    <td>{{rows.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{rows.an}}</td>
                    <td>{{rows.den}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <form id="add-content" ng-controller="addInfoCtrl" ng-submit="addInfoDb()">
                <br/>
                <div class="controls">
                        <button type="submit" style="width: 220px;">Adauga salariu</button>
                </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript file:

```
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', '$document', function($scope, $sce, $document) {  
    $scope.showSal = [
        { id: '1', an: '2016', den: 'Oracle' },
        { id: '2', an: '2016', den: 'Oracle' }
    ];
}]);

app.controller('addInfoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
    $scope.testAdd = { id: '100', an: '2016', den: 'Oracle' }

    $scope.addInfoDb = function() {
        $scope.showSal.push($scope.testAdd);
        console.log($scope.showSal.length);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: You should use `track by $index` and in your *add* function, you need to actually create a duplicate object, maybe like `angular.copy( objToCopy )`

Comment: using `track by $index` work just fine https://jsbin.com/vufidedoti/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: ngRepeat:dupes Duplicate Key in Repeater

Add `track by $index`

```
ng-repeat="rows in showSal track by $index"
```

[Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)

Comment: The project is bigger of that I posted here and with 'track by $index' it wasn't worked.... I don't know why... but with @Yuva Raj solution it works very good.

Comment: @Doro This really is a better answer than the one you picked. The `angular.copy()` function makes a deep copy of whatever you're passing, which is expensive for both memory and time efficiency. `track by $index` simply specifies an alternate distinguisher during the `ng-repeat` iteration, and throws in some extra accessibility for free. If `track by $index` isn't working for you, you probably messed up the usage and should fix it, rather than going with a notably less efficient route.

Comment: Human error.... very big error :) ... I was altering another ng-repeat tag and, of course, it couldn't have how to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace,

```
    $scope.showSal.push($scope.testAdd);
```

to,

```
    $scope.showSal.push(angular.copy($scope.testAdd));
```

[Here's the working FIDDLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/OEyiRVNzAY54SqJVlOzP?p=preview)